# using angularjs promises add two random numbers. program not running

Tags: angularjs

```
app.service("service1",function($q){
  this.number1 = function(num1) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var num1=Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
    var result1 = num1
    deferred.resolve(result1)
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
app.service("service2",function($q){
  this.number2 = function(num2) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var num2=Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
    var result2 = num2
    deferred.resolve(result2)
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
app.service("addservice",function($q){
  this.addition = function(num1 , num2) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var result = num1+num2
    deferred.resolve(result)
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});


app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, addservice,service1,service2) {
  service1.number1().then(function(data){
    $scope.result1=data;
  })
  service2.number2().then(function(data){
    $scope.result2=data;
  })

  addservice.addition().then(function (data){
   $scope.result = data;
 })
});
```

first service is used to pass num1 and second one is used to pass num2.
Third service is used to pass addition.
Do we use promise.all to sync multiple promises?
Or what can we do here.?

Comment: firstly, you are not passing your numbers as parameters, e.g. you have `.addition()`, instead of `.addition($scope.result1, $scope.result2)`. But yes, you need to sync them with `$q.all(...).then(function(data){ addservice.addition(data[0], data[1]).then(...) })`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey you should create a full answer

Comment: @AlekseySolovey yes full answer, please.